# Constructors calling other constructors: any performance issues?

Tags: .net, performance, constructor, method-chaining

In an application where performance is crucial, would there be any noticeable advantage of *Scenario 1* (completely separate constructors) vs. *Scenario 2* (chain-calling constructors)?

**Scenario 1**

```
Class TwoInts

    Private a, b As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
        Me.a = a
        Me.b = b
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer)
        Me.a = a
        Me.b = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        Me.a = 0
        Me.b = 0
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Scenario 2**

```
Class TwoInts

    Private a, b As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
        Me.a = a
        Me.b = b
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer)
        Me.New(a, 0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(0)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there wouldn't be a noticeable difference.

You can run your own benchmark and find out.

Answer (score 0):

The speed should not be very different. Thjere are only 2 more calls from the bare constructor to the deep one... but:

You should ask the language C# what it thinks about constructors that call constructors :P
There it would not go very well, so I think you should stick with a different approach like making an "Initialization method", and call that from each constructor, and have a more readable code. There you would need to use the ": this(0)" Notation which is not so readable (eg. procedural when reading it). And it would have one less call to get to the point of doing something.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by noticeable. Scenario 1 does introduce extra calls, but the time it adds will be measured in fractions of a millisecond. Scenario 2 will be faster. (It will also increase the size of the generated code.)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use a common Init() method as proposed by Marino Šimić!** 
It is C++ style and not suitable for C#. In C# initialization should be done in the constructors!

For details see Bill Wagners book "Effective C#":

http://www.diranieh.com/NETCSharp/EffectiveCS.htm#14._Use_Constructor_Chaining